# Mudar cor de parte de uma string

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta no MySQL e mudar a cvor de uma parte do texto, se estiver contida no texto uma string específica.

Por exemplo: 
Minha tah td retorna um texto

```
<td id="conteudo" class="tablesaw-priority-5 tablesaw-cell-visible>{{$value->conteudo}}</td>
```

Se este texto retornado tiver uma substring qualquer por exemplo: XXXX

Eu preciso que este XXXX fique em vermelho  e o restante na cor original em preto.

É possível realizar isto?

Comment: A substring que precisa mudar de cor é padrão, ou seja, será sempre o mesmo texto?

Comment: Não @Andre o texto muda de acordo com o resultado do SELECT no banco. Mas a cor pode ser sempre a mesma.

Comment: E palavras que possuam o termo devem também ser destacadas? Por exemplo, ao buscar por "tipado", a palavra "constipado" deverá ser destacada por possuir "tipado"?

Comment: não é necessário, só o código mesmo.

Comment: você esta usando algum framework ou template engine? (blade, twig...)

Comment: @Lorena Mas o código muda dependendo da resposta.

Comment: Isso é feito no PHP ou em Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de alterar parte de uma string.

```js
var valor = "Aqui vem o resultado da sua string";
var termo = "resultado";

var str = valor.replace(termo, "<span class='AlteraCor'>" + termo + "</span>")

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.AlteraCor{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Teria como eu mudar a cor do texto que estivesse dentro de dois caracteres específicos? Ex: entre os caracteres # e : Ex #Olá Mundo:  Deixando o Olá Mundo com outra cor.

Answer (score 5):

no `template engine` você pode usar qualquer função disponivel no `PHP`, sabendo disso podemos usar a função `preg_replace` que substitui um texto de acordo com uma expressão regular, veja:

```
$texto = "este é o texto-que-eu-quero"
$formatado = preg_replace("/texto-que-eu-quero/", "<span>xxx</span>", $texto);
echo $formatado; // A saída será "este é o <span>xxx</span>"
```

Seu código:

```
<td
    id="conteudo"
    class="tablesaw-priority-5 tablesaw-cell-visible>
        {{ preg_replace("texto-que-eu-quero", "<span>xxx</span>", $value->conteudo) }}
</td>
```

Desta maneira você pode aplicar um `css` apenas no span e poderia utilizar em qualquer lugar. (não esqueça de aplicar uma classe no span para evitar conflitos)

```
span {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Curiosidade: poderia utilizar a tag `<mark>` que já destaca o texto por padrão e deixa o conteúdo semântico.